How to get all system properties from device
I want to get ro.vendor.build.security_patch in my app but there is no api for this purpose. I can read property ro.build.version.security_patch using Build.VERSION.SECURITY_PATCH but not all properties are available.
All properties can be found using this command:
adb shell getprop


It is possible to run adb shell getprop from app and then parse result.
This is a sample kotlin code for getting ro.vendor.build.security_patch:
val vendorSecurityPatch = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(Runtime.getRuntime().exec("getprop").inputStream))
    .lineSequence()
    .find { it.contains("ro.vendor.build.security_patch") }
    ?.dropWhile { it != ':' }
    ?.filterNot { it in listOf(':', '[', ']') }
    ?.trim() ?: ""

It exceutes getprop command in device shell and parse result by filtering result. Then remove unwanted characters.
